# Is there a more elegant way to write this Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I practice SQL commands on HackerRank website and I came across this challenge:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-12/problem

The query needed is this one:

> Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

My solution is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE city NOT LIKE ('A%') AND city NOT LIKE ('E%') AND city NOT LIKE ('I%') AND city NOT LIKE ('O%') and CITY NOT LIKE ('U%') AND city NOT LIKE ('%a') AND city NOT LIKE ('%e') AND city NOT LIKE ('%i') AND city NOT LIKE ('%o') and CITY NOT LIKE ('%u');
```

This one works fine but it looks very ugly and verbose.
Is there an elegant solution to this problem?
Also please in Oracle SQL flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(city,1,1)) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
  AND UPPER(SUBSTR(city,-1,1)) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
```

or:

```
WHERE INSTR('AEIOU', UPPER(SUBSTR(city,1,1))) = 0
  AND INSTR('AEIOU', UPPER(SUBSTR(city,-1,1))) = 0
```

I try to avoid using regular expressions when there is a "traditional" alternative as regular expressions in SQL are slow!

Comment: Thank you! This also looks more simple than a regex. As a beginner this looks more clear to me and easy to understand.

Comment: This only checks the first character as it stands, see the dupe for also checking the last character

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(city,1,1)) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
    AND UPPER(SUBSTR(city,-1)) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U');

Comment: @Daniel you got it!

Comment: @MartinSmith True, I didn't read the spec, just the OP's attempt!  Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regexp, like:

```
where not regexp_like(city, '^[aeiou]', 'i')
```

Regexp `'^[aeiou]'` means: `'a'` or `'e'` or `'i'` or `'u'` at the beginning of the string. The third argument, `'i'`, makes the match case-insensitive.

Please note that this only checks that the city does not start with a vowel. If you want to also check that it does not end with a vowel, then:

```
where not regexp_like(city, '(^[aeiou])|([aeiou]$)', 'i')
```

Comment: Please elaborat on the downvote. If something is wrong with this answer I am willing to improve it.